# Simultaneous triangularization of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, change-of-basis, triangularization

If I have two matrices $A$ and $B$, where both have the same eigenvalues and $B$ is positive definite, is it possible to simultaneously triangularize them?
So that there exists an invertible matrix $P$, s.t. $PAP^{-1}$ is triangular and $PBP^{-1}$ is triangular?

Actually, I want to do this with these two matrices:

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\quad B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

If not, would it be possible to make them both block-diagonal?